# Press key and hold event for button in Winform

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to make a button change its fore color when we press a key. Like button's name is "A" and we press A it changes the fore color into red, then we release the key it turns back to its default color. But I can't find any such event.
Thank you! :D

Comment: Winform, wpf, asp.net, etc?

Comment: Ohh sorry!!! I forgot. Edited

Comment: It's win form. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's `KeyDown`, `KeyPress`, and `KeyUp` event you should use.

Refer to this link.

http://csharp.net-informations.com/gui/key-press-cs.htm

Comment: Thank you! I did it. Need 3 more mins to accept the answer :D

Answer (score 1):

If you want to capture a key typed anywhere on a form, you can use `Keydown`, `KeyPress` and `KeyUp` like ydoow said, but you will also have to set the form's `KeyPreview`property to true to make sure your events are raised even if a key is typed while in a specific control.